# Exceeding data payload limit in Work Manager

Tags: android, download, android-jetpack

I am trying to download a list of images using Work Manager in android. I have a List which I am encoding in JSON string using Gson and passing to Data in work manager.

The problem is, I have amazon s3 links which are really long and my data limit quickly exceeds 10240 bytes (data payload limit that you . an send to work manager via .setData())

Can anyone suggest a better way to pass data into work manager. Or will I have to persist it somewhere :( ?

Comment: You should persist your data to *db or shared prefs* and then obtain it in `doWork()` method.

Comment: Note that [MAX_DATA_BYTES](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Data.html#MAX_DATA_BYTES) is 10 kilobytes, not 1 kilobyte.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Thanks for pointing out. I've edited my question. The payload is exceeding 10 kilobytes.